# flutter firebase: Bad State

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having trouble with my code. It's always returning `Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform`.

I don't know what I did wrong. It used to work but after sometime and then I started getting this error. I didn't change anything about it. I didn't touch it. All of a sudden started receiving this error. And it doesn't work anymore. Not at all.

```
final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
  QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>? selectedRide;

StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collectionGroup('Requests')
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }

            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final request = snapshot.data!;
                  String currentID = request.docs[index].get('UID');
                  if (currentID == uid) {
                    return Card(
                      child: ListTile(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedRide = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                          });
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => MyRidesPageScreen(
                                      selectedRide: selectedRide)));
                        },
                        title: Row(
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(
                              width: screenWidth * 0.1,
                              child: Text(
                                request.docs[index].get('Departure date'),
                                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: screenWidth * 0.03,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: screenWidth * 0.27,
                              child: Text(
                                request.docs[index].get('Departure city'),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: screenWidth * 0.02,
                              child: const Text(
                                '-',
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: screenWidth * 0.03,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: screenWidth * 0.27,
                              child: Text(
                                request.docs[index].get('Arrival city'),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: screenWidth * 0.1,
                              child: Text(
                                request.docs[index].get('Departure time'),
                                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  return const SizedBox();
                });
          }),
```

This is the screenshot. Any help?

[image: error screen]

Comment: Can you let us know which line is causing this issue?

Comment: No line shown. It only gives the error

Answer (score 1):

You are see only one condition `!snapshot.hasData` but not considering any other condition and trying to build the `data` using `ListView.Builder`, but you need to consider situation when the stream is in `ConnectionState.waiting` and the like

Change your `Streambuilder` structure to:

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: ...,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data?.isNotEmpty == true) {
            return ListView.builder(); // Your ListView Builder here
          }
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ).
```

Comment: Changed it but still doesn't work

Comment: @EbenOasis, please find my edited post

Comment: Still no. and also snapshot.data?.isNotEmpty throws an error.    The problem is that the code I wrote used to work. Then later started working intermetently. But does not work at all.