# Flutter firebase Stream builder not satisfying conditions

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-streambuilder

My streamBuilder on my app is giving me problems. The problems (on the same screen) are different and I will show you what they are.

This is the stream

```
final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('ADS');

StreamBuilder(
stream: users.doc(uid).snapshot
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
*****conditional statements******})
```

Statements 1 - In this statement all my emulators return the `snapshot.hasData` condition even if they don't have data. Sometimes also it returns `Bad state`.

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return Container( padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15, left: 15),
                      child: const Text(
                        "You already have an active ad. You can't have a multiple ads!!",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    );
                  }

if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return const Text(
                      "No data found",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    );

else return const Text(
                    "OKOkokoK",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  );
```

Statements 2 - This also returns the `snapshot.hasData` conditions for in all the emulators even when don't have data.

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return const Text(
                      "No data found",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    );
                  }
return Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15, left:15),
                    child: const Text(
                      "You already have an active ad. You can't have a multiple ads!!",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  );
```

This means that the app is taking only the if condition `snapshot.hasData`, ignoring the rest of the condition. What should I do?
I check suggestions from the following links but none helped

[Condition does not work when using a streamBuilder in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63293367/condition-does-not-work-when-using-a-streambuilder-in-flutter)
[flutter firebase: Bad State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75878152/flutter-firebase-bad-state)